# Pushing element to dynamically allocated pointer array int C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

[EDIT 1] I'll preface by saying that for this project, I am required to "Create a container class" where I can push, pop, and retrieve elements from a list. I am supposed to use pointers, and must write the functions for pushing, popping, etc. [/EDIT 1]

I am having difficulty pushing an element to a dynamically allocated pointer array. I am able to initially create an array just fine. You can see from my comments my thought process for how I think I should be able to add to the array:

```
1) create new array with room for the one new element;
2) add the new element to index 0;
3) copy the old array into the rest of the new array;
4) delete old array;
5) set the new array as the value of the pointer
```

I have the following three files:

IntegerList.h:

```
/** 
*IntegerList.h
*/

#ifndef IntegerList_H
#define IntegerList_H

class IntegerList
{
private:
    int * pArray;
    int length;

public:
    IntegerList(); // default constructor

    void createArray(int howlong);
    int getValue(int index);
    void deleteArray();

    void pushFront(int element);
};

#endif
```

IntegerList.cpp:

```
/**
* IntegerList.cpp
*/

#include "IntegerList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// IntegerList constructor:
IntegerList::IntegerList()
{
    pArray = 0;
    length = 0;
}


// creates an array of length howlong (determined by main.cpp); sets the values
// to equal ten times the index number. For example, if an array of size 4 is
// to be created, then an array with the following values will be created by
// this method: 0, 10, 20, 30. Sets length equal to howlong.
void IntegerList::createArray(int howlong)
{
    length = howlong;
    pArray = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
        pArray[i] = (i*10);
}


int IntegerList::getValue(int index)
{
    return pArray[index];
}


void IntegerList::deleteArray()
{
    delete[] pArray;
}


// places element at front of array
void IntegerList::pushFront(int element)
{
    // create new array with room for the one new element
    int newArray[length+1]; // nope

    // start by adding the new element
    newArray[0] = element;

    // copy the old array, put it into the new array starting at index 1 (since
    // index 0 is the new element)
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
    {
        newArray[i+1] = pArray[i];
    }

    // delete old array
    deleteArray();

    // set pArray equal to the new array;
    pArray = newArray;

    // update the value of length
    length += 1;
}
```

And my main file, main.cpp:

```
#include "IntegerList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create object
    IntegerList myArray;

    // create array of length 5
    myArray.createArray(5);

    // print array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        cout << "Element " << i << ". " << myArray.getValue(i) << endl;

    // everything works ok so far

    // push the number 99 to front
    myArray.pushFront(99);

    // print array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
        cout << "Element " << i << ". " << myArray.getValue(i) << endl;

    myArray.deleteArray();
}
```

The first printArray() shows that everything is going as planned. However, after I try to push 99 to the front, things get screwed up :(

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
Element 0. 0
Element 1. 10
Element 2. 20
Element 3. 30
Element 4. 40

Element 0. 99
Element 1. 0
Element 2. 2130567168
Element 3. 4486648
Element 4. 2686508
Element 5. 4201772
```

Note that in the second printout, the first two elements appear to have the value that I intended for them to have.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask why all the raw array usage in c++?

Comment: do you want to push some values in every element?

Comment: `int newArray[length+1];` besides being non-standard to C++ that VLA is local to that member function. With `pArray = newArray;` you're saving the address of an array that is literally going to cease to exist once the function returns. Any reference or dereference once that happens invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: This is an incredibly inefficient and error-prone approach. Just use `std::vector` and its `push_back` method.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf They want new element on index 0, so `push_back()` isn't an option. I'd use `vector.insert(vector.begin(), value)`.

Comment: I am all in favor of beginners learning to handle arrays before moving up to std containers, as I think it teaches valuable lessons. In this case, the lesson is "don't keep pointers to dead things".

Comment: @Saraph; (1) I do not see the requirement you speak of, but rather the term "push", and an inefficient O(n^2) implementation of that. (2) If the array items are desired in the opposite order, one can simply visit them in the opposite order. (3) For a more permanent reversal there's `std::reverse`.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. Forgot to mention: this is for an assignment that asks us to "create a container class" using a dynamic array, and to use pointers :/

Comment: why not use the `std::list` class, it has `push_front()`, `clear()`, methods already efficiently implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can force your way to make static arrays of variable length, but it's in violation of standard.

```
int newArray[length+1];
```

will not work. Make it

```
int * newArray = new int[length+1];
```

instead.

As others in comments said, reallocating an array after every single insert is extremely inefficient and tedious work. Consider using some of these:

- `std::vector`
- `std::stack` (as you're inserting on the beginning of your container)
- `std::list`
- your very own linked list

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code for pushing and got it to work properly. Revised code is below. Notice I had to assign the **values** form the `tempArray` back into the "original" array (`pArray`), not the address of `tempArray`.

```
void IntegerList::push(int value){
    // when this method is called to push a value onto an empty array, that is,
    // when length = 0, it first creates an array of length 1
    if(length == 0)
        pArray = new int[1];

    // create temp array
    int * tempArray = new int[length+1];

    // add new value to index 0
    tempArray[0] = value;

    // add old elements
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        tempArray[i+1] = pArray[i];

    delete[] pArray;

    // initialize pArray with proper size
    pArray = new int[length+1];

    // copy elements of tempArray into pArray
    for(int i = 0; i < length+1; i++)
        pArray[i] = tempArray[i];

    delete[] tempArray;

    length += 1;
} // end push
```